# Getting a strange int value

Tags: c++

When I `cout` my `lettercase` variable to the console, I get `-858993460`. Everything else seems to be working okay. What am I missing here?

So here's a sample of my code:

Here's main:

```
int main()
{
    int lettercase = 0;
    Switch switcher(lettercase);
    lettercase = switcher.getLettercase();
    cout << "Lettercase: " << lettercase << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I also have a separate class called `Switch`.
Here's a sample of its header file:

```
class Switch {
public:
    // DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    Switch();

    // OVERLOAD CONSTRUCTOR
    Switch(int);

    // DESTRUCTOR
    ~Switch();

    // Lettercase accessor
    int getLettercase();

private:
    int lettercase;
};
```

And here's a sample of my definition:

```
// DEFAULT
Switch::Switch() {
    int lettercase = 0;
}

// OVERLOAD
Switch::Switch(int lettercase) {    
    // CHANGE LETTER CASE
    if (lettercase == 1) {
        lettercase = 0;
    } else {
        lettercase = 1;
    }
}

// DESTRUCTOR
Switch::~Switch() {
}

// ACCESSOR
int Switch::getLettercase() {
    return lettercase;
}
```

Comment: You have a million comments to annotate every triviality, yet you manage to give the class member and the function parameter *the same name*?! Talk about the need for a Darwin award for C++...

Comment: -858993460 is not a strange value.  Converted to hex, it is 0xcccccccc.  Whenever you see that back in the debugger when you use MSVC++ in the Debug build then you go "ah, I'm using an uninitialized variable!".  Standard bug.

Comment: @Janisimo: In addition to the issue mentioned in the answer, a similar issue exists in the constructor. You are initializing a local variable in the constructor, while the class member remains uninitialized.

Comment: The answer has now been edited to cover the issue in the default constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// OVERLOAD
Switch::Switch(int lettercase) {    
    // CHANGE LETTER CASE
    if (lettercase == 1) {
        lettercase = 0;
    } else {
        lettercase = 1;
    }
}
```

You have scope issues here.  You're trying to change the class variable `lettercase`, but because the argument for the constructor is also called `lettercase`, you have to use `this->lettercase` if you want to access the class variable.  I suggest changing the name of your parameter here.

Something like this:

```
// OVERLOAD
Switch::Switch(int initCase) {    
    // CHANGE LETTER CASE
    if (initCase == 1) {
        lettercase = 0;
    } else {
        lettercase = 1;
    }
}
```

The reason you were getting that odd int is because your scope issues prevented you from ever initializing the class variable `lettercase`, but your getter was still accessing this variable and returning the uninitialized value.

EDIT: Your default constructor also has a problem, here:

```
Switch::Switch() {
    int lettercase = 0;
}
```

This isn't doing what you think it's doing (or what you want it to do).  Rather than initializing the class variable, `lettercase`, this is creating a new variable, `lettercase`, (scope) and initializes it to 0.  Instead, your default constructor should look like this:

```
Switch::Switch() {
    lettercase = 0;
}
```

Comment: A similar issue exists in the constructor. The code is declaring and initializing a local variable in the constructor, while the class member remains uninitialized.

Comment: @AndreyT Edit: I see what you're talking about.  And now I edited my answer to cover that issue as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really have to look into this more.